# How to pass parameters in system call in Perl?

Tags: r, perl, system-calls

I'm calling R function in Perl by passing variables in Perl program using system command.

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
  $file1= "Test1.txt"
  $file2= "Test2.txt"
  $val="Rscript Test.R ".$file1." ".$file2;
  print($val,"\n");
  system('Rscript Test.R', $file1, $file2);
```

But it does not call the R script and pass the file1 and file2 values. How can I fix this?

Comment: What result do you get?

Answer (score 6):

When using the `system LIST` syntax, put all the arguments to the list - otherwise, `Rscript Test.R` is taken as one command.

```
system('Rscript', 'Test.R', $file1, $file2);
```